# Prevent flashing of BIOS from Windows with full administrator capabilities

Tags: windows, usb, bios, administrator

I'm experimenting with installing Windows on a USB flash drive for use on public computers. Since this drive is my own, I would like full administrator privileges, since it's also my own Windows installation. However, I can't because of one glaring issue: you're normally able to update/flash/overwrite the BIOS on the computer.

There are many utilities out there, often from the motherboard's manufacturer, enabling you  to update the BIOS (flashing it). This can also be used for other purposes, like corrupting the BIOS. I don't want this to be possible, yet I do want full administrator access for the Windows installation itself.

Thus, I was wondering whether it was possible to make it impossible to flash the BIOS from a Windows installation (booted from a USB flash drive) with full administrator capabilities. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Please also note that in many situations you won't be able to boot from USB because the BIOS will have been locked down or the terms of use will stipulate against it... Either way, you _must_ get permission to do this from the relevant authority (IT Department) before doing so.

Comment: I do have permission, as long as I find a way for them to prevent me from flashing the BIOS. I have updated my question with additional information. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: I mean what it boils down to is that you can't both have complete unrestricted access to this local install of Windows without also providing you the ability to update the BIOS. The Windows trust model is based on the fact that the person who controls the hardware also controls the software, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: no.

If you have Admin rights, you have admin rights - period. Either they trust you enough to let you use your portable Windows installation, or they take away your admin rights.

A simpler solution may be to launch a hypervisor of some sort, as most will typically hide the entry points for flashing the BIOS from its guests. This has its own set of challenges, but I believe you won't find a good solution that combines "portable USB mode" with "Admin rights", without "block flashing the BIOS".

Also, remember that the IT staff can lock down the BIOS with a password. While not perfect, at least on Dells, it will block even Administrators on Windows from flashing without the password. It's also very easy (without the BIOS password) to flash a BIOS, even if you do not have Administrator rights, so I think the IT staff are looking in the wrong areas.

Comment: We are able to lock down the BIOS with a password and make it work. So if we lock down the BIOS and boot Windows from a flash drive with full administrator privileges, will flashing the BIOS become impossible? Is there any way to check this? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: You can always test it by trying it out, with IT's supervision. Again, I'm basing this on my experience with Dell machines - if a BIOS Admin password is set, it will not let you flash without that password, period.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! Your answer answered my question very well.

Comment: That's the goal :P